# Ubuntu firewall to block/allow applications

Tags: linux, firewall

I'm looking for a Firewall for Ubuntu to block/allow single applications.
I'd like it to have a GUI.

I found [Leopard Flower personal firewall for Linux (LPFW)](https://github.com/themighty1/lpfw) but I need to run `sudo ./lpfw` and `gui/gui.py` everytime I access my computer to make it start and works.

It would be nice to have an application like [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall) (which is an Android app).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Gufw Firewall](http://gufw.org/)** looks like it could match your needs:

[image: Gufw screenshot]
<sup>*Gufw Firewall* (source: [ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw); click image for larger variant)</sup>

I have not tried it out myself, but according to [some screenshots](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw) it seems to fulfill your requirements:

- **Firewall for Ubuntu:** Yes
- **block/allow single applications:** According to the screenshot: Yes (see the "Application" drop-down and, below that, the "Application filter". What makes me doubt this a little is reading between the lines: *options for controlling firewall options for common programs and services* could also be interpreted like "Selecting *Postfix* it would block ports 25, 465 and 587 (smtp/smtps/submission) *globally for the device*". This is not clarified on the page.
- **have a GUI:** Yes, as the screenshot proves.

There's a [list of Linux firewall GUIs](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/little-known-gui-firewall-options-for-linux.html), but I'm afraid none of those has the "per application" feature.

#### Related questions/answers on our sister sites

- [Linux per program firewall similar to windows and mac counterparts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5451206/2533433) (SO)
- [How to control internet access for each program?](https://askubuntu.com/q/45072/68291) (AskUbuntu) – this a.o. mentions [Douane](http://douaneapp.com/) which looks like *exactly* what you're after – but the Douane page currently throws an 503 (check [the page in Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.douaneapp.com/) meanwhile or rather see [their Github presence](https://github.com/Douane/Douane))

---

As the AU article suggests, **[Douane](https://github.com/Douane/Douane)** seems to match your needs exactly:

> When Douane is started, it will watch the ougoing network traffic and as soon as an unknown application tries to send some network packets, Douane will block it and ask you if you allow it or not:
>
> [image: Douane]

What's left open in the description is whether you can define "exceptions" or make your choices permanent (imagine that popup appearing on each Firefox request) – which I *assume* can be done in the *rules* tab of the *Douane Configurator:*

[image: Douane Configurator]
<sup>*Douane Configurator* (source: [Douane](https://github.com/Douane/Douane); click image to enlarge)</sup>

So let's check this one against your requirements:

- **Firewall for Ubuntu:** Yes (but currently needs to be installed manually, see below)
- **block/allow single applications:** Yes (see screenshots for prove, also the above linked AU article explicitly says so)
- **have a GUI:** Yes, as the screenshots prove.

Drawback: [Packages](https://github.com/Douane/Douane/wiki/Packages) are currently only available for ArchLinux, <s>so you'd have to [compile and install](https://github.com/Douane/Douane/wiki/Compilation) it manually.</s> Note there's already [an open request for Ubuntu packages](https://github.com/Douane/Douane/issues/45).

**Update:** Meanwhile there's a [Douane PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ezedtux/+archive/ubuntu/douane) available for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried `Gufw Firewall` but it just allows you to select some default applications and not all applications I have in my system. About `Duane` it's very good for me, but the site is not working now and I don't know why. And where can I download the package? Also can I trust that application? I can't find the code on github https://github.com/Douane/Douane

Comment: Installation instructions can be found behind my [compile and install](https://github.com/Douane/Douane/wiki/Compilation) link. The code seems to be in separate repositories (douane-dkms, douane-daemon, douane-dialog, douane-configurator).

Comment: @Frank Incidentally, I was reading an article on Douane and came across your question later on. Perhaps, the article may help you out in basic setup and know-how. http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-per-application-firewall.html

Comment: Izzy, is Duane another name of Douane or is it a typo at many places?

Comment: @Firelord typo I'd say – at least in my writing, as the underlying links reveal. Sorry for that – but French isn't really my strength ("douane" AFAIK is French for "customs").

Answer (score 3):

Being searching for a proper GUI firewall for over 5 years and have been using firestarter, ufw, gufw with variable success. Douane was tricky to compile, and on a recent 64bit ubuntu fails to compile.

Recently ran into [Opensnitch](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch) which was comparatively easy to install and use on a ubuntu box. It has two processes: a networking process that must be run as root, and a GUI process that runs under the current user.

It is not in standard repos, but the instructions on the github page are pretty straightforward.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Douane was looking way more complicated to compile and get working and this one seems to have a nicer gui. I'm going to check it out.

Comment: The evilsocket repo appears to be abandoned however [this fork](https://github.com/gustavo-iniguez-goya/opensnitch) is actively maintained and currently working well in Ubuntu 20.04  :)